# Why does the guilds.join scope exist?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was wondering what the use of the `guilds.join` scope is, and can you show some examples of how to use it? I'm just curious of what people use this for.

Can I use it to join my bot support server?

Comment: because it probably an array?

Answer (score 1):

`guilds.join` allows you to add the user who used the URL to a guild the bot is in. Note the bot does need `CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE` permissions in that guild.

You will need a URL like this:

```
https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&response_type=token&scope=guilds.join
```

Now when they authorize, the URL they got redirected to, specified as the redirect URI, will have a URL parameter that has the access token. You can use this with the discord.js function [`GuildMemberManager#add()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=add), which works like this:

```js
guild.members.add(userId, { accessToken: "ACCESS_TOKEN" })
```